# Alpine image unable to resolve more than 63 IP addresses for domain (`java.net.InetAddress`)

Tags: java, alpine-linux, inetaddress, libnet

I'm using:

- Docker image: `alpine:3.18.3`,
- Java: `openjdk11-jre`:

```
openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20+8-alpine-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20+8-alpine-r0, mixed mode)
```

##### Problem description:

When I try to use `java.net.InetAddress#getAllByName` to get all IP addresses for host with more than 63 addresses I'm getting exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 70ips.test-domain.com: Name has no usable address
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:930)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
    at com.issue.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

It looks that the native implementation of `java.net.InetAddress#getAllByName` in `libnet` is failing.
I encountered this problem only for Alpine image. For other Linux distribution (e.g. Ubuntu) it seems that there is no such a problem. The problem does not appear when the host is resolved for less than 64 IP addresses.

##### Reproduce the problem:

1. Create record of type `A` using Route 53 in AWS [see documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html) with host `70ips.test-domain.com` and 70 IPs as a value;
2. Create Java code which resolves IP addresses for that host:

   ```java
   import java.net.InetAddress;
   import java.net.UnknownHostException;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.stream.Collectors;

   public class TestApp {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
       final String host = "70ips.test-domain.com";

       final InetAddress[] all = InetAddress.getAllByName(host);

       printResults(all, host);
     }

     private static void printResults(InetAddress[] all, String host) {
       final String addressesAsString = Arrays.stream(all)
         .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
         .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "\n", ""));
       final String msg = String.format(
         "URL: '%s'. InetAddresses[%s]: %s",
         host,
         all.length,
         addressesAsString
       );
       System.out.println(msg);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create Docker image based on Alpine image using Dockerfile like:

   ```
   FROM alpine:3.18.3
   RUN sed -ie "s/https/http/g" /etc/apk/repositories
   RUN apk add \
         --no-cache \
         --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main \
         ca-certificates
   RUN apk add openjdk11-jre
   COPY target/app-jar-with-dependencies.jar app.jar
   CMD ["sh", "-c", "exec java -jar app.jar"]
   ```
4. Run the docker container using command: `docker run <image_name>`;
5. In logs there will be exception:

   ```
   java.net.UnknownHostException: 70ips.test-domain.com: Name has no usable address
       at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
       at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:930)
       at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543)
       at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
       at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
       at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1386)
       at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1307)
       at com.issue.Main.main(Main.java:27)
   ```

##### Questions:

1. Is 63 IP addresses some known limitation?
2. Do you know how can I fix the issue?

##### Expected and actual outcome:

I tried to use `java.net.InetAddress#getAllByName` to get all IP addresses for host with more than 63 addresses. I expected to get the array of IP addresses for given host. Actually I got exception `java.net.UnknownHostException` with "Name has no usable address" message.

Comment: I suggest opening a bug to Alpine.

Comment: Created [Alpine issue](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/15320).